# Replacing both upper case and lowercase findings

Tags: search, substitute

I often find myself running the following commands in sequence when wanting to replace both the lower case and title case instances of a given word, while retaining its original case.

```
:'<,'>s/Foo/Bar/g
```

```
:'<,'>s/foo/bar/g
```

is there a clean way I can combine the above two commands to achieve the same outcome?

Comment: @biggybi It does! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Plug-in [tpope/vim-abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) can help with that. It implements a `:Subvert` command, which is similar to `:s` but takes care of case variants (and potentially plural forms.)

In your case, after adopting the plug-in, you could simply use:

```
:'<,'>Subvert/foo/bar/g
```

See [“Substitution”](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish#substitution) in the plug-in documentation for addition examples.